# Any status update, on an iOS example for Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

The following response on github mentions that an iOS sample is under active development. I'm just wondering if there's been any timeframe update. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16 ... Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No updates yet, but rest assured it's not forgotten or being ignored.

(Update 2016-01-01:  This answer is still current;  it's still being worked on.)

Comment: Have you heard anything new?  Looking at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16 I don't see anything new. Maybe there's a better link to track the progress?

Comment: Nope, but I'll ask @petewarden if he can post an update if there's anything new.